# Issue with NSScrollView

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview, ikimagebrowserview, nsscroller

I have a NSScrollView containng an iKImageBrowserView. If I do not call setWantsLayer:YES on the scrollview, the vertical scroller is never shown. 
Do you know what can be the issue and hos to fix it (activating layers creates other issues in my app)

Thanks for your help,

Regards,

Comment: Try `[NSScrollView setHasVerticalScroller:YES]`;`